# Why is this perl script so slow?

Tags: performance, perl

I have written a `perl` script to implement in the `polymake` framework.

The script accomplishes the following task. It's input is a matrix `$M` from `polymake`. Issuing

```
print ref($M);
```

returns

```
Polymake::common::Matrix_A_Rational_I_NonSymmetric_Z
```

The output of the script is a matrix whose rows are the rows obtained from `M` by taking all the sums of all subsets of rows of `M`. For example, the input of

```
1 0 0
1 3 0
1 0 3
```

returns

```
0 0 0
3 3 3
2 3 3
2 0 3
1 0 3
2 3 0
1 3 0
1 0 0
```

The code for my script is

```
use application 'polytope';
use Data::PowerSet 'powerset';

sub newVertices {
    my ($orig) = @_;
    my $n = $orig -> rows;
    my $vert = zero_vector($n);
    my $d = Data::PowerSet->new( {min => 1}, map {"$_"} (0..$n-1) );
    while (my $r = $d -> next) {
        my $v = new Vector($n);
        foreach (@$r) {
            $v += @$orig[$_];
        }
        $vert = $vert / $v;
    }
    return $vert;
}
```

The script works fine. My issue is that the script runs a lot slower than I think it should. The example I mention above takes about half a minute to run. My questions are

1. Am I correct to expect that such a task should be able to be accomplished quickly for matrices with relatively few rows?
2. Why is this script so slow?
3. Is there a way to accomplish this task more efficiently?

I suspect the problem might be the matrix object type I am dealing with it and maybe writing a script that does this purely with arrays might be more efficient. My problem is I cannot figure out how to transition from an array back to a matrix so I haven't made an attempt to do something along these lines.

Comment: Take a look at Devel::NYCProf and use it to benchmark your program.

Comment: >Is there a way to accomplish this task more efficiently? http://www.polymake.org/doku.php/reference/clients

Comment: @simbabque Correction - It's Devel::NYTProf https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf

Comment: @dave ouch. Typo :-( thanks for correcting me

Comment: Could it be because you are creating a new Vector object in every loop of your while loop.. ?

Comment: There could be several reasons why your script is slow, but it's difficult to tell.
You could start considering a few things like:  
* Not using "new" at every iteration. That takes time, try using one variable and just clearing it.  
* If you have two cycles nested, normally you'd have an O(n^2) running time. In this case though, I'm not so sure, since having an nxn matrix and adding everything to another nxn matrix may mean having an O((nxn)x(nxn)) = O(n^4) running time.

Comment: I'm with @simbabque, fire up nytprof, let it dump to HTML and then browse the report with a web browser, and you can drill down a little.  You might consider moving the inner loop to its own subroutine, so that the profile can give you a better picture of how much time is spent running the inner loop vs. the outer loop.

Comment: As to not creating a new Vector in each iterations, you could use creat one vector outside the loop, and then use Storable::dclone() to make a copy inside the loop.

Comment: In the interest of pedantry, you should use Benchmark.pm to benchmark bits of your program (e.g. to see if one version is faster than the other - cloning vs new Vector). You should use a profiler to get the timings of function calls. Using a profile will make your program run longer, as it gathers, collates and records all its info. The profiler will identify hot spots in the code, and as such is an amazing tool to have in situations like this.